# Add new callback like "beforeMigrate_V1.0.0.sql" (new feature)

Tags: flyway

We knew there were some callbacks in flyway: beforeMigrate,beforeEachMigrate,afterEachUndo...

Our project need to fix a problem in an indicated version sql such as V1.0.0 without modify V1.0.0.sql.

Is there any way to help us? Should we support new an Event BEFORE_INDICATED_VERSION_MIGRATE to work with new callback file like **beforeMigrate_V1.0.0.sql**?

Take for an example:
we missed

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

in V1.1.0.sql so we want to callback it while migrating only before V1.1.0.sql.
So we add the below sql in beforeEachMigrate.sql:

```
SELECT version INTO @max_ver FROM `schema_version` ORDER BY version_rank DESC LIMIT 1;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = IF(@max_ver = "1.0.9", 0, @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS);
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = IF(@max_ver = "1.1.0", 1, @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS);
```

In general condition it works. But if we add V1.0.9.1 one day, it won't work.
Is there any ideas?

Comment: Why you cannot modify V1.0.0? It will fail because of checksum but checksum can be updated in existing database before deployment. Is your question how can you insert some kind of migration before existing migration (by adding sql file)?

Comment: It is an enterprise product and cannot be modified. Suppose user deployed V2.0.0 and we modified V1.0.0, then we had to use flyway repair to repair the checksum.  That is permission denied in general conditions.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't do this like you suggested, you can easily add a `V1.0.0.1__my_additional_change.sql` file which will then automatically be applied after `1.0.0` and before `1.0.1` when migrating the database.